# Anyway to make use of jquery ui tabs spinner with pagemethods?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, webforms, jquery-ui-tabs, pagemethods

I am using Jquery ui tabs with asp.net webforms and I'm loading the content with ajax. I actually have two problems

1. I don't know how to load the content for the first tab load. Right now I use the tabsselect to load content via ajax.

   $('#contentHolder').bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
          // run ajax request
       });
2. The build in spinner control only seems to work when I use actual paths for the href. But since I have to use pagemethods I need to use an id instead.

- One
- Two
- Three

// ajax request to pagemethod

$.ajax...

**Updated Code**

```
 // tab initializaztion
        var $tabs = $('#followersTable').tabs({ spinner: 'Loading...'  });

        $tabs.bind("tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
            //LoadTabContent(ui.index);
              var request = {
                'controlName': 'FollowersTab'
              };

            $(this).tabs({
                ajaxOptions: {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/Followers.aspx/LoadTabContent",
                    data: $.toJSON(request),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(container).html(data.d);                                      
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: First of all data: $.toJSON(request) this part is useless. Because request variable is already a JSON object. it should be "data: request". I will update answer later on additionally

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:
`$("your-tabs-selector-here").tabs( "load" , 0 );` this will force your tab first tab to be loaded via ajax.

If I didn't get it wrong; you could use [WebMethod] for your page methods and you can combine your page methods with UI Tabs ajaxOptions. You can play with ajaxOptions for return type and/or method name ..etc

```
$( "your-tabs-selector-here" ).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                         type: "POST",
                          url: "Default.aspx/PageMethodName",
                          data: "{}",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: "json"
            }
        });
```

Comment: You could also have look at below example for jQuery ajax and Page methods. So you can integrate with UI and your components.  http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/04/GridView-Grouping-Master-Detail-Drill-Down-Using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: Will that trigger the spinner text / animation or is that only triggered by using a url for the tab href?

Comment: if you use "Default.aspx/PageMethodName" for first tab, this method should trigger spinner and rest of functionality that Ui tabs supports.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.. I'll update my post with the code I am using